# How can I change the form on clicking "Save", and then submit the final version of the form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I have a form with a variable number of textboxes, and when I click Save (the submit button), I want it to remove the empty ones and then save the form without the empty boxes.

But it's only half-working.  When I click Save, the empty boxes are visually removed. Moreover, usually there's a validation error when boxes are left empty, but with removeEmptyBoxes() there is no validation error so I know the boxes are somehow successfully removed before submit.  But when the page refreshes, the empty boxes reappear.  On the other hand, if I divide it into two buttons and use one button to removeEmptyBoxes() and then click the other button to Save, that works fine and the deleted boxes stay deleted.

I'm sure I can get round this in a completely different way, but it's frustrating that it doesn't work the way I want it to.  Is there any way to do this?

My form is made using Ajax.BeginForm.  My button looks like this:

```
<input name="xiSubmit" type="submit" value="Save" onclick="removeEmptyBoxes()" />

function removeEmptyBoxes() {
  $('div.box').each(function () {
    var content = $(this).find('.box-content').val();

    if (content == '') {
      removeElement(this);
    }
  });
  return true;
}
```

---

solution: my removeElement() function consisted of a slideUp to hide the box nicely and then removing the box completely.  I removed the slideUp bit and it all worked fine.  Not sure why it didn't work with the slideUp.

Comment: When you submit a form, you are served up a FRESH copy of the page. Of course the boxes are going to be there again.

Comment: No, the form saves the number of boxes.

Answer (score 2):

For a form with id `myForm`:

```
$('#myForm').submit(function(ev){
    ev.preventDefault();  // prevent the original form submit
    // do your thang
    $(this).submit();  // submit form with your changes
});
```

Comment: Hmm, that still saves the form with the empty boxes back in. It rouses the suspicion that my deleteEmptyThoughts function just hides rather than deletes the boxes, except for the fact that if I separate them into two buttons, the form is saved without the deleted boxes as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Given this simple form:

```
<form id="theForm" method="post">
    <div class="box">
        <div class="box-content">
            Test
        </div>
    </div>
    <input name="xiSubmit" type="submit" value="Save" />
</form>
```

You can add javascript like this:

```
$(function() {
    $("#theForm").submit(function() {
        $('.box-content',$('div.box')).remove();
    });
});​
```

The above submit handler is executed before the form is actually submitted, so you can do any pre-processing you'd like.

Here's a JSFiddle you can play around with: http://jsfiddle.net/cTwMW/.  Notice I added `return false` at the end of the fiddle javascript so the form doesn't submit (allowing you to see the jquery remove the element).

Comment: Hmm, that still saves the form with the empty boxes back in. It rouses the suspicion that my deleteEmptyThoughts function just hides rather than deletes the boxes, except for the fact that if I separate them into two buttons, the form is saved without the deleted boxes as expected.

Comment: If you use jQuery's `.remove()` function it should remove the HTML elements completely from the DOM